# How to rerender View after change boolean value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have two components i pass data from child to parent 
in child commponent i have

```
 sendIsMutiple(fileNumber: number) {
    let isMultiple: boolean
    if(fileNumber > 1) {
      isMultiple = true;
    } else {
      isMultiple = false;
    }
    this.isMultiple.emit(isMultiple);
  }
```

In parent .ts file

```
  isMultipleFileLoaded: boolean = true;  
  reciveMessage($event) {
    this.isMultipleFileLoaded = $event; 
  }
```

and html file

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="column-left">
        <app-document-info *ngIf="isMultipleFileLoaded" ></app-document-info>
    </div>
</div>
```

and how to do that when isMultipleFileLoaded change value from true to false was visible or unvisible. Now my boolean value is changed but view is allways visible.

Comment: "and how to do that when isMultipleFileLoaded change value from true to false was visible or unvisible"...Can you rephrase this sentence.Its confusing

Comment: can you console.log( this.isMultipleFileLoaded  ) after   this.isMultipleFileLoaded = $event;  and see if the value is actually getting received. and please post full code for parent.ts

Comment: @Vikyath Maiaya is working now my method pass only true and isMultipelFileLoaded don't changed

Comment: Sorry what ?Is the event change is working or not?I mean whether the true false value only isnt emitting properly or ,true false value value from the child is emitted properly but not reflected in the template ..Wich one is it ?